# How to rewrite folder access to a specific file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to setup the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(?=health-safety/.*)([^/\.]+)/?$ course-list.php?id=1 [L]
```

so if somebody enters `/health-safety` it will redirect to `course-list.php?id=1`

I have other rules going on, so it needs to detect if it's for health-safety.

Comment: And what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they will be entering www.yoursite.com/health-safety/, this rule should work:

```
RewriteRule ^health-safety/?$ course-list.php?id=1 [L]
```

If there will be an additional path, you may need this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^health-safety/([^/\.]+)/?$ course-list.php?id=$1 [L]
```

In the second example www.yoursite.com/health-safety/5 would display www.yoursite.com/course-list.php?id=5